# Implementing functions in an interpreted programming language

Tags: java, interpreter

Before I write about my question, just a little background information. I'm writing a toy programming language in Java since I've become fascinated with compilers/interpreters and the like. I've got the basics down in this small language, it's along the lines of:

```
ADD 5, 6 -> c
PRINT c
# will store 11 into c
```

It's very basic, but it's a start. Since I'm only 16, I just cant read books about technical things, they're very dull/bland to me, I like reading articles on the internet, or the little tutorials people post on HN (writing scheme in C for example). Anyhow, I'm really confused on how to implement functions in a language, e.g

```
# only integers since that's easier than multiple data types
FUNC whatever(a, b) -> return a + b
# used like
PRINT whatever(5, 6)
```

The only way I could implement functions would be really hack-y and turn into a jumbled mess of spaghetti. I want to know the 'proper' method of implement functions into a programming language. A little info on the language: I haven't implemented AST's since I haven't learnt them yet, I wrote a lexer for the language which works well, the parser is very simple and just parses from top to bottom, left to right (forgot the technical term for this, recursive descent parser?).

Sorry if this is a bad question, vague, anything like that. Never posted anything on stack overflow before, and I've written some code in attempt to implement functions but deleted it since it didn't work too great (this was a few days ago), and I'm asking this since I want to have a set plan of implementation, and that I'm confident it will work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you start with expression evaluation using the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It's very easy to implement using 1 or 2 stacks (depending upon whether you output RPN notation or execute immediately).

I've used the shunting-yard algorithm for [several](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/617/advanced-calculator/8732#8732) [little](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/568/basic-calculator/8723#8723) [interpreters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2381+[interpreter]) for math expressions ([discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.lang.postscript/algebraic$20mode/comp.lang.postscript/RKtP0nL5XWs/fYAOtigR-MkJ)).

For functions, of course you'll need to define a structure to hold all the function's information like number of variables, local variable names, and some representation of the function's *code* which can be executed.

If you use a call stack, you can push the local arguments on to the stack. You will then need to "compile" the executable representation so it uses stack offsets instead of the variable names. Alternately, you can use a stack of hash-tables as a namespace stack. You will then need to lookup variables in each hash-table from the top down until the variable is found. With either of these ways, local variables will obscure global variables with the same name (which is what you want).

With the shunting-yard algorithm, you will need to perform some book-keeping in response to the parentheses. So, with your example

```
PRINT whatever(5, 6)
```

`PRINT` is presumably recognized as a statement-type which executes the following expression and then prints the result. So you'll see this expression as several distinct tokens.

```
whatever    (   5   ,   6   )
```

`whatever` can be discovered to be a function-name if it was previously defined. But if you want to allow functions as *first-class citizens*, this still might not be a function-call until you see the parens. (Maybe you want to just print the code of the function.)

An identifier followed by a left paren `(` however, is clearly the start of a function call. We then need to recursively evaluate each comma-delimited expression, and arrange for these results to be used as the arguments to the function. With the call-stack method, just push the two results. With the namespace stack, define the two variables and push the hash-table.

Then call your *function-call-handling* function to evaluate the function's code. And use the result as the result from evaluating the whole expression, by printing it.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Is there any resources you could recommend me to where I can learn how languages work on the stack level?

Comment: This seems like a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 0):

This code tries to interpret a very simple programming language by using a top-down recursive-descent method.  It uses the split() method to separate tokens. Written in Python.

```
stmt-list = stmt | stmt stmt-list

stmt =      id ":=" expr ";" |     print expr ";"

expr = term {("+"|"-") term} .

term = factor {("*"|"/") factor} .

factor =     id     | intnum     | floatnum     | "(" expr ")" .
```

---

```
import sys
from sets import Set
parsed = []
words = []
token_set = Set(['+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')'])
token_map={'+':'SUM','-':'SUM','*':'DIV','/':'DIV','(':'LEFT_PAR', ')':'RIGHT_PAR'}

def stmt(line):
    for word in line.split():   
        if word == 'SUM':
            expr(line)
        elif word == 'DIV':
            term(line)
        elif word == 'LEFT_PAR':
            checker = False
            wordgrp = words(line.split())
            for word in wordgrp:
                if word!='LEFT_PAR' and not checker:   
                    break
                elif word == 'LEFT_PAR' and not checker:
                    checker = True
                elif checker and word != 'RIGHT_PAR':  
                    parsed.append(word)
                elif checker and word == 'RIGHT_PAR':   
                    stmt(parsed)    
        else:
            break

def expr(line):
    for word in line.split():
        if (word == '+'):
            factor(line);
        elif word == '-':
            factor(line);
        else:
            break

def term(line):
    for word in line.split():
        if (word == '*'):
            factor(line);
        elif word == '/':
            factor(line);
        else:
            break

def factor(line):
    syntax_checker = True
    if (syntax_checker):
        print(line)
        syntax_checker = False
    else:
        print("Syntax Error");

file = open(sys.argv[-1], "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    stmt(line)

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old thread, but some time ago I've implemented a small interpreter for language similar with JavaScript (with more restrictions), the code is published in Github at https://github.com/guilhermelabigalini/interpreter

But it does support IF/CASE/LOOPS/FUNCTIONs, see below:

```
function factorial(n) {
  if (n == 1) 
    return 1;

   return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

var x = factorial(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these 4 steps:

1. Get the name of the function and then the code

   (a) get the *function name* enclosed between two `:` chars, for example `:Name:`.

   (b) check for parenthesis after the *function name*, for example `:Name:(print "Hey")`.
2. Assign this code to its *function name* in a *dictionary*, for example `Name: print "Hey"`.
3. Create another *lexer* and *parser* because it doesn't work in the first parser and lexer. It just executes the whole time or it only does one line of code.
4. Take the code, run it through the *lexer*, and then through the *parser*. When the user wants it to run, you assigned the function like this: `:Name: (print "Hey")`. To call it you add a *call* for example the *keyword* was `do`. So if it was `do :func:` it checks wether it is in the *dictionary*. If yes, then it runs it through the *lexer* and then through the *parser*. If not, it gives an error.

#### Missing parameters

The function doesn't have parameters yet but I'll update this answer as soon as I figured out how to do.